# B2C custom policy calling a rest api

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a custom policy in B2C which is calling a rest api. Currently, when running the policy, when the technical profile which calls the rest api is reached, the profile waits for the api to return a response.

After adding the rest api in, there is now a noticeable additional delay in the time it takes for the policy to complete. Which will be the time it takes for the rest api to run.

However, my rest api is used to just pass a set of data in. There is no value that the api returns to B2C that is then used. Is it therefore possible to change the custom policy so that once the call to the rest api is made, then it doesn't wait for a response from it, but instead carries on with the next step in the custom policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no you cannot change that behaviour. I would suggest to change the API it is calling to send a queue message to start a background job to do the work. Then the API can return back faster and B2C won't need to wait for the work to finish.

Comment: I thought this might be the case. Thanks for answering.